# Roles for queue.yaml deployment with service account

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to deploy our `app.yaml` and `queue.yaml` using the following command:

```sh
gcloud --verbosity=debug --project PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml queue.yaml
```

I created a new service account with the roles

- App Engine Deployer
- App Engine Service Admin
- Cloud Build Service Account

for deploying the `app.yaml`, which works by itself. When trying to deploy the `queue.yaml`, I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--project: "PROJECT_ID", --verbosity: "debug", DEPLOYABLES:1: "[u'queue.yaml']"]
DEBUG: Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x7fcc7dba0dd0>]
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
Configurations to update:

descriptor:      [/home/dominic/workspace/PROJECT/api/queue.yaml]
type:            [task queues]
target project:  [PROJECT_ID]


DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 117, in Run
    default_strategy=flex_image_build_option_default))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 606, in RunDeploy
    app, project, services, configs, version_id, deploy_options.promote)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/output_helpers.py", line 111, in DisplayProposedDeployment
    DisplayProposedConfigDeployments(project, configs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/output_helpers.py", line 134, in DisplayProposedConfigDeployments
    project, 'cloudtasks.googleapis.com')
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/enable_api.py", line 43, in IsServiceEnabled
    service = serviceusage.GetService(project_id, service_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/serviceusage.py", line 168, in GetService
    exceptions.ReraiseError(e, exceptions.GetServicePermissionDeniedException)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/exceptions.py", line 96, in ReraiseError
    core_exceptions.reraise(klass(api_lib_exceptions.HttpException(err)))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/services/serviceusage.py", line 165, in GetService
    return client.services.Get(request)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/serviceusage/v1/serviceusage_v1_client.py", line 297, in Get
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
GetServicePermissionDeniedException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

I've also tried the following roles:

- Cloud Tasks Admin
- Cloud Tasks Queue Admin
- Cloud Tasks Service Agent

I'm using the Project Editor role for now, which works but I would like to only permit the roles which are actually required.

Comment: For deploying, you will need the `App Engine Admin` role. The `App Engine Deployer` will not suffice, as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles). "Note: The App Engine Deployer role alone grants adequate permission to deploy using the Admin API. To use other App Engine tooling, like **gcloud** commands, you must also have the Storage Admin role."

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Cloud Tasks Queue Admin role, you have to [add `Service Account User`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#sa) to allow the service account of Cloud Task to generate token on behalf the service account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now have the roles App Engine Deployer
`App Engine Service Admin`, `Cloud Build Service Account`, `Cloud Tasks Queue Admin`, `Service Account User` assigned to the service account but it's still throwing the `PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission` error

Comment: Are you sure you have all the required APIs enabled on your project ?

Comment: @Waelmas sorry for the late reply, missed the comment. Yes, I believe so because I'm using the `Editor` role to make deployments for now. But would like to reduce the permissions for this service account. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Was banging my head against the wall for awhile with this myself, it seems "intuitively" you also need "serviceusage.services.list" perms, so Service Usage Viewer role

found via this issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137078982